# Getting null at workbook

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am beginner in selenium webdriver, I have created a main class in these I have created an object of writable class and in these I get the "testSuitName" and then it goes to the writable class.

In writable class I have created an constructor and pass the string, in these I get the value.

After that when I try to get the workbook it displayed the null but the way I have given an path is correct according to windows OS. Also, in "testSuitePath" I get my workbook.

Below are the snapshot which I have taken at the time of debug:
[image]

I am not able to get the problem that, where I am going wrong?
Can any one please help to resolving it.

Below are constructor where this line has written:

```
public WritableData(String testSuitePath, String OBJECT_REPOSITORY_PATH) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

         try { 
        Workbook wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath)); 
        WritableWorkbook wwbCopy= Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath),wbook);
         System.out.println("writable workbookC-->" +wwbCopy);
        WritableSheet shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet("Login");
         System.out.println("writable sheetC-->" +shSheet); 
          } catch (Exception e) { 
             // TODO: handle exception 
             System.out.println("Exception message" + e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }
```

Comment: Do you pass an absolute or a relative path?

Comment: @Frank absolute one.

Comment: Ok. Can you place the following line before `wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(...)` and set the breakpoint after that new line ´File workbookFile = new File(testSuitePath)`? Then look if you really have a File-object. Could you furthermore post your testSuitePath?

Comment: Hmm, if the file exists but Workbook says it can't find it then perhaps there's something wrong with the file. Workbook tries to read the FileInputStream it creates from your file. If it can't read it an BiffException with the message you mentioned is thrown. Try to delete and recreate the file. Oh, and be sure to store it in the old Excel-Format as problem scan be caused by the new format as far as I know.

Comment: @Frank After reading the WritableWorkbook object when it comes to the WritableSheet object line it displayed the warning "unsupported supbook type - ignoring".

Comment: Could you post more code?

Comment: @Frank Here you go now, I have posted the constructor where this lines are written.

Comment: The message "unsupported supbook type - ignoring" comes from the constructor of WriteableWorkbook. So I unterstand that the original problem (wbook is null) is resolved?

Comment: I got the mistake its too silly, actually problem is here in script sheet name is mentioned as "Login" but in workbook sheet name is different. So, that is why its displaying the null. Anyways thanks for your effort @Frank :)

Answer (score 0):

At that point you have paused BEFORE executing the `Workbook.getWorkbook(...)` method, so the value is still `null`.

If you step one more line you should see a value there.

Comment: After that it throws an exception "The input file was not found".

Comment: Well, that's pretty clear, no?  Make sure `testSuitePath` contains a valid path to a file.  Also you should have mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: Yes I have given an correct path thtat's why I am not getting that why it don't take.. :(

Comment: Clearly you believe it's correct and also clearly it is not.  Most likely the path is relative and the current directory is not what you are expecting. Since you haven't shown us the value we cannot help.